# Latest Java/OS X Update broke My Ant

Tags: java, macos, ant

All kinds of issues since I updated to 10.6.4 and the latest java update.

My install of ant can't find anything!

```
[javac] /Users/path/to/my/build.xml:458: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 8 source files to /Users/path/to/WEB-INF/classes
[javac] Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
```

Line 458

```
<javac
  nowarn="on"
  destdir="${media.classes}"
  fork="true"
  debug="true"
  target="1.5"
  memoryMaximumSize="${maxHeapSize}"
  bootclasspathref="bootclasspath"
>
```

Where bootclasspath is defined

```
<path id="bootclasspath">
    <fileset dir="lib/xml">
        <include name="xalan-2.7.1.jar"/>
        <include name="xml-apis.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${java.home}/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Can you show us what's on line 458?

Comment: Added! Thanks for the request. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `bootclasspahtref` on line 458 to `ilrn.bootclasspath`

Comment: Changed to be more consistent names.

Comment: @bobber205.  Can you drop java.home from you `<path>` definition and change `bootclasspathref` to `classpathref`?

Comment: @bobber205. Also found this http://www.coderanch.com/t/503097/tools/warning-includeantruntime-was-not-set on the warning you are getting

Comment: Did what you asked in the 2nd comment and getting "symbol not found" errors instead on each of the files.

Comment: @bobber205.  Any reason for '1.5' target?

Comment: Fixed the issue by changing boothclsspathref to classpathref where I found it and putting in the complete path for the lib folder for Java instead of relying on java.home and it compiles now. :D